# How do I solve tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"?

Tags: python, tkinter

After I click my <kbd>clear results</kbd> button (`update()` function) in which it closes and restarts the code again, when I input numbers into `Entry` function I get a

```
tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"
```

message and nothing occurs.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Prime number interval finder')
root.geometry('500x400')

e = Entry(root, width=50, bg="grey", fg="white", borderwidth=5)
e.pack()

d = Entry(root, width=50, bg="grey", fg="white", borderwidth=5)
d.pack()

e.get()
d.get()

e.insert(0, "Enter First number in interval")
d.insert(0, "Enter Second number in interval")

def myClick():
    lower = int(e.get())
    upper = int(d.get())
    for number in range(lower, upper+1):
        if number > 1:
            for i in range(2, number):
                if number%i == 0:
                    break
            else:
                c = number
                a = Label(root, text=str(number))
                a.pack()

def update():
     root.destroy()
     exec(open("actualcode.py").read()) 

myButton = Button(root, text="Click me!", padx=10, pady=10, command=myClick)
myButton2 = Button(root, text="Clear results", padx=10, pady=10, command=update)
myButton.pack()
myButton2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. I suspect the problem is in `actualcode.py`.

Comment: `exec(open("actualcode.py").read())` is an anti-pattern. The correct way to run code from another script is to import it.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<string>", line 22, in myClick
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3043, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"

Comment: The error is telling you that you've destroyed the entry widget. Once a widget has been destroyed, it can't be used again.

Comment: You destroyed all your widgets when you did `root.destroy()`. The code in `actualcode.py` is trying to use the entry.

Comment: okay, so what would be the best way of getting back my entry widget or closing the program without actually destroying it

Comment: What exactly do you want to destroy in the root — or conversely, keep?

Comment: I'd like to keep everything but I know realistically that is not possible. Would there be another way to create a function that refreshes the window without actually destroying it?

Comment: @Barmar: You're right (in a sense), because `actualcode.py` is the script that is being executed's own name and that is indeed where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big part of the problem is how you're trying to restart the script by having it re-execute itself via the `exec()` function after deleting the `root` window. Here's a better way to accomplish that that doesn't use that approach — instead it keeps a list of what widgets it needs to destroy in order to start over. It also has additional function to re-prompt the user to enter new values (erasing any that were previously entered).

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Prime number interval finder')
root.geometry('500x400')

labels = []  # Global list to hold Labels created to show numbers generated.

e = Entry(root, width=50, bg="grey", fg="white", borderwidth=5)
d = Entry(root, width=50, bg="grey", fg="white", borderwidth=5)
e.pack()
d.pack()

def display_prompt():
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, "Enter First number in interval")
    d.delete(0, END)
    d.insert(0, "Enter Second number in interval")

def clear_labels():
    """Remove any existing number labels."""
    for label in labels:
        label.destroy()
    labels.clear()

def myClick():
    lower = int(e.get())
    upper = int(d.get())

    # Create labels for prime numbers in range.
    clear_labels()
    for number in range(lower, upper+1):
        if number > 1:
            for i in range(2, number):
                if number%i == 0:
                    break
            else:
                a = Label(root, text=str(number))
                a.pack()
                labels.append(a)

def update():
    clear_labels()
    display_prompt()


myButton = Button(root, text="Click me!", padx=10, pady=10, command=myClick)
myButton2 = Button(root, text="Clear results", padx=10, pady=10, command=update)
myButton.pack()
myButton2.pack()

display_prompt()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes so much sense.